# OSX / Xcode / Objective-C: How to detect the version of Flash Player installed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit

I need to take different action depending on the version of Flash Player installed on OS X (due to a Flash bug). Is there a way to programmatically ascertain the version number?

I am using WebKit for this, BTW.

EDIT:

I also tried

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: @"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/Info.plist"];
```

And although the pathname exists. "myBundle" is always nil.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that there may not be any version of Flash installed.  I'm pretty sure that the currently-shipping version of Mac OS X doesn't come with Flash; users have to install it from Adobe.

Comment: Yes. True. The detection should be ready for a "nothing installed" scenario

Comment: What are you writing?  A web browser?  A browser plug-in?  Some other kind of native app that uses the Flash player?

Comment: It's a web browser that run inside one of our utility windows and goes to a pre-determined website that happens to run flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use anything that will let you at the `CFBundleVersion` of the currently installed plugin. Something like this works in a shell scripting environment:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print CFBundleVersion' /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Flash\ Player.plugin/Contents/Info.plist
```

There might be a way to search the system's list of installed applications for a bundle ID matching `com.macromedia.Flash Player.plugin` and pull out the bundle version from the system record, as well.

***EDIT***: It looks like both `NSWorkspace` and Launch Services just map items to bundle IDs of relevant apps, and then will map a bundle ID to a URL or `FSRef`. So ultimately, with this approach, you have to grab the appropriate bundle and pull out the version from there.

There's likely also a way to get this information from some JavaScript code running within the webview. Adobe's `SWFObject` seems to make this quite easy, for example. For more, see ["Detecting Flash Player versions and embedding SWF files with SWFObject 2"](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html).

Comment: For finding the plugin's bundle folder, `mdfind 'kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == "com.macromedia.Flash Player.plugin"'` will do the trick nicely.

Comment: I tried the following, but "myBundle" is always a "nil" - NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.macromedia.Flash Player.plugin"]; [myBundle load]; // not sure why!

Comment: @Ron M.: That will not look outside your app bundle. You need to use the appropriate `NSWorkspace` method or Launch Services function (whichever you prefer) to locate the bundle URL for that bundle ID. You can then create the `NSBundle` using that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave off the `Contents/Info.plist` part; you need to get the bundle, not its Info.plist:

```
NSBundle* flashBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: @"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin"];
NSString flashVersion = flashBundle.infoDictionary[(id)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

Remember to cover the case when there is no Flash Player installed.